# Why does bill.xpath("//p/font/a")[index].text return "undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass" using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm new to Ruby, so please forgive me if this is a simple question.

I'm getting the above error with this block of code:

```
bills = doc.xpath("//p[@align='left']/font[@size='2']")
@billsArray = []
bills.each_with_index do |bill, index|
  title = bill.xpath("//p/font/a")[index].text
  link  = bill.xpath("//p/font/a")[index]['href']
  @billsArray << Bill.new(title, link)
end
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through the items I'm getting back from my `xpath` call and display each one...doesn't seem to be working.

If I take the `index` out of my title variable, I get this error: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. Based on the `[]` in the error, I'm assuming `[index]` isn't actually returning a value...isn't something wrong with the way I setup my loop?

The end goal is to display the link & link text of all links on this page: http://billstatus.ls.state.ms.us/2016/pdf/misc/h_cal.htm

Here's the full code of the file:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  class Bill
    def initialize(title, link)
      @title  = title
      @link   = link
    end
    attr_reader :title
    attr_reader :link
  end

  def scrape_house_calendar
    # Pull in the page
    require 'open-uri'
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://billstatus.ls.state.ms.us/2016/pdf/misc/h_cal.htm"))

    # Narrow down what we want and build the bills array
    bills = doc.xpath("//p[@align='left']/font[@size='2']")
    @billsArray = []
    bills.each_with_index do |bill, index|
      title = bill.xpath("//p/font/a")[index].text
      link  = bill.xpath("//p/font/a")[index]['href']
      @billsArray << Bill.new(title, link)
    end

    # Render the bills array
    render template: 'scrape_house_calendar'
  end
end
```

Comment: You are trying to iterate each item in your bills active record collection right ? are you sure it contains the records to iterate with each one ?

Comment: No, I'm actually iterating through the `doc` variable I get back using `open-uri`:

Comment: yes according to your query [ bills = doc.xpath("//p[@align='left']/font[@size='2']") ] the variable bills will contains a collection if your code working fine, so just debug the bills variable to check if it contains any collection of records.

Comment: What is it you think *index* should contain, and why would you index into a nodeset?

Comment: @CodeGnome I thought index would contain the current index of the array as Ruby loops through the billsArray. I'm actually not sure what you mean by indexing into a nodeset...I'm totally new to Ruby & Nokogiri.

Comment: I am asking if the bills variable contains some data or not, just check it in rails debug prompt.

Comment: @PraveenGeorge Yes, the bills variable contains data — double checked in debut prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

When I created by my `bills` variable, I didn't go deep enough in the xpath (I think)... I changed my `bills` variable to equal `doc.xpath("//p/font/a")` and it worked.

Comment: Still not fully sure why, so I'm totally open to an explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is telling you that you're attempting to call a method on an object that is nil. Why it's nil is something you'll have to debug as time permits.

However, with a little refactoring, you can fix your XPath and zip up all your node results into an array of arrays without all that indexing. For example:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://billstatus.ls.state.ms.us/2016/pdf/misc/h_cal.htm'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open url)
@bills =
  doc.xpath("//p[@align='left']/font[@size='2']").map do |node|
    node.xpath("//p/font/a/text()").map { |tnode| tnode.text.strip }.zip \
    node.xpath("//p/font/a/@href").map(&:to_s)
  end.first

@bills.first
#=> ["H. B. No.  899:", "../../../2016/PDF/history/HB/HB0899.xml"]
```

You can then convert the array any way you like before feeding it into your Rails view.